# Como Usar o Onde IN na consulta no laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, where

Como posso realizar uma consulta abaixo com o mysql no laravel:

```
SELECT
    gps.positions.id,
    gps.positions.protocol,
    gps.positions.deviceid,
    gps.positions.servertime,
    gps.positions.devicetime,
    gps.positions.fixtime,
    gps.positions.valid,
    gps.positions.latitude,
    gps.positions.longitude,
    gps.positions.altitude,
    gps.positions.speed,
    gps.positions.course,
    gps.positions.address,
    gps.positions.attributes,
    gps.positions.accuracy,
    gps.positions.network,
    sing.veiculos.identificacao,
    sing.veiculos.id_tipo,
    sing.veiculos.descricao,
    sing.veiculos.deviceid
FROM gps.positions
LEFT JOIN sing.veiculos ON sing.veiculos.deviceid = gps.positions.id
WHERE gps.positions.devicetime IN ((SELECT MAX(devicetime) FROM positions GROUP BY deviceid));
```

Desde já agradeço e fico sem aguardo de uma luz.

Comment: Você pode utilizar a `Facade DB` e utilizar o método estático `raw() `para fazer uma instrução `SQL`, por exemplo `DB::raw('SELECT ...') .`

Qualquer dúvida sempre bom dar uma lida na documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma outra maneira aparentemente mais simples fazer o que deseja:

```
$dados = DB::table('tabela')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

**Para mais informações:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries